# How to get async/await to wait for my nested array to fill

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I am having an issue where I can see the array and the data of "arrayOfResults", but when I try to access a certain part of the array, it says undefined.  I know it has something to do with the asynchronous call because if I put console.log on a timeout it displays correctly. I'm pretty new to async calls in general, let alone awaits.  Thanks for the help!

```
async function convertToCSV() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("thing").value; //value from text area
        var arrayOfUserInput = userInput.split('\n').map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '')); //converts userInput to array and removes whitespace
        var arrayOfResults = new Array();

        //iterates for how many user inputs are recorded into arrayOfUserInput
        for(i = 0; i < arrayOfUserInput.length; i++){
       //awaits for each result of retrieve data before inputing into arrayofresults
         arrayOfResults[i] = await retrieveData(arrayOfUserInput[i]);

        }
        //*****THIS IS THE PART NOT WORKING CORRECTLY****
       console.log(arrayOfResults[0][0]);
     }

     async function retrieveData (clientRecord){
        //pulling data from API
        var request = require("request");
        var resultsArr = new Array();
        var options = { method: 'POST',
        url: 'blah',
        body: ''

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {

        var resData = JSON.parse(body);   //stores json response into object

        // Do Work here
        return  resultsArr;

     }
```

When I console.log arrayOfResults[0] I recieve all of the data correctly.

When I console.log arrayOfResults [0][0] like above I get undefined unless I put a timeout in to actually wait for the results.

Comment: async/await (Promise) code and callback code don't work with each other. Promisify  `request`.

Comment: In other words, the `retrieveData()` function must return a promise that will be resolved.

Comment: can we simplify the question, at its current stage its bit complicated to read, you will get better responses if  you can condense the problem.

Comment: @RandyCasburn is the code/comment from Devzer0 on the right track? I tried implementing his code and am still getting the same results. Thanks again guys for your time!

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {

        var resData = JSON.parse(body);   //stores json response into object

           if(resData.data.policy_number !== undefined){
             //...........
           } else{
               resultsArr[0] =resData.messages[0];
           }
           resolve(resultsArr);
        });
    });
```

i codified what Randy suggested for you to get a better idea,

Comment: I tried implementing this, but when I did I get the same results. Just to clarify: the convertToCSV function should work correctly as long as I implement the promise in my retrieveData function? I inserted the "return new Promise" after "async function retrieveData (clientRecord)."

Comment: Don't do stuff in asynchronous callbacks (especially stuff that will throw, like `JSON.parse`!) - use promise callbacks instead! Or better yet, just use the `request-promise` package instead of manually promisifying.

Answer (score -1):

To clarify the hack, underneath is an easy example with more vivid approach of async/await.

```js
async function addOneInArray() {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let sumArr = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sumArr[i] = await add(arr[i]);
  }
  return sumArr;
}

function add(number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(number + 1) }, 100)
  })

}

addOneInArray().then((result)=>{
    console.log("Sum element of an Array by 1 - ",result);
});
```